# python search file within specified range

Tags: python

I am trying a program to search for a word in text file within a specified area only.
Consider a text file having text as:

```
dynamic means changing  
change good  

tickme 1
 python is good
 its dynamic
 and precise

tickme 2
 its rapid  
 its best
 well and easy
```

i have a list which contains 'dynamic' .I need to search 'dynamic' within 'tickme 's' only.If dynamic is with 'tickme' then it has to output as:

```
tickme 1
 its dynamic
```

I tried a coding where it can only print 'dynamic' from overall file but i need only within tickme.Please help!

```
mylist = []
with open('programt.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in mylist:
            if key in line:
               print line
```

Please help!Answers will be appreciated..

Comment: can u add some more data of text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tickme=""
with open('a.txt','r') as file:

    for line in file:
        if 'tickme' in line:
            tickme=line
        if line.startswith(' '):
            if 'dynamic' in line:
                print searchstring
                print line
```

explanation :

1. store the tick me value in tickme
2. we know inside tickme the lines start with a space from beginning that differs from the first line